# Python 2.7 os.path.isfile

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am testing the os.path.isfile(path) method to see if something is a file or not. Strangely I find that if I join the path and file name it returns true, but if I put the full file path it returns false. Why is this?

```
import os

path = 'C:\Users\usrname\Documents\test.xlsx'

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('C:\Users\usrname\Documents','test.xlsx')): #returns yes
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'

if os.path.isfile(path): #returns no
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

Python 2.7 on Win 7 iPython Notebook

Comment: inspect the output of os.path.join('C:\Users\usrname\Documents','test.xlsx')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the `\t` in the path is a tab character, not a two character slash-t. Use raw strings.

```
path = r'C:\Users\usrname\Documents\test.xlsx'
```

or escape the separator

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\usrname\\Documents\\test.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `\t` is being converted into a tab.

```
import os
path = 'C:\Users\usrname\Documents\test.xlsx'
print path

# C:\Users\usrname\Documents    est.xlsx

path = os.path.join('C:\Users\usrname\Documents', 'test.xlsx')
print path

# C:\Users\usrname\Documents\test.xlsx
```

To avoid the problem of escape characters altogether, I would suggest just building the string completely using `os.path.join`.

```
base_dir = os.path.join('C:', 'Users', 'usrname', 'Documents')
print base_dir

# C:\Users\usrname\Documents

path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test.xlsx')
print path

# C:\Users\usrname\Documents\test.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

Because os.path.join convert you path  string to correct path:

'C:\\Users\\usrname\\Documents\\test.xlsx'